# Distriqt Dialog ANE - MultiSelectBuilder error

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, dialog, air-native-extension, distriqt

Hello I am building an app and I am using Dialog ANE.

I need to display a MultiSelect dialog for iOS with 5 different options and initial values for those options. I copied the example that comes with the ANE to show this dialog. When I display the MultiSelect dialog, values array passed displays correct, however selectedItems does not work correctly, it doesn't mattar values inside. I tried also without any initial values and the dialog displays that one element is selected.

I am using this ANE also for other dialogs and it works correctly. Is there anything I am missing?

Here it's my code:

```
if (Dialog.isSupported)
    {
        _dialogType = multipleSelectVO.type;
        _dialogData = multipleSelectVO.data;
        var values:Array = multipleSelectVO.options[0];
        var selectedItems:Array = multipleSelectVO.options[1];
        // values and selectedItems length is the same.
        var multiSelect:DialogView = Dialog.service.create(
                new MultiSelectBuilder()
                        .setTitle( multipleSelectVO.tittle )
                        .setAcceptLabel( "OK" )
                        .setCancelLabel( "Cancel" )
                        .setValues( values/*, selectedItems */) //I tried with both and just values.
                                                                // Dialog is not display correctly
                        .build()
        );


        multiSelect.addEventListener( DialogViewEvent.CLOSED, multiSelect_closedHandler );
        multiSelect.addEventListener( DialogViewEvent.CANCELLED, multiSelect_cancelHandler );
        multiSelect.addEventListener( DialogViewEvent.CHANGED, multiSelect_changedHandler );
        multiSelect.show();
    }
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You might want to show exactly what the selectedItems array contains? It must be an array of Boolean values the same length as the values array for it to work correctly.

Comment: Hello Michael, I forgot to add that the array of selected items contain Booleans, however when I don't give any array of Booleans, just values, it shows by default that one of the values is selected.

Comment: Can you replicate the issue with some code we can test? ie a simple array

Comment: Actually I've been able to reproduce this issue, looking into it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with the ANE, in particular the multi-select wasn't correctly converting the array of values into the selected row indexes.

We have corrected the issue now and an update will be available shortly. Check github for the update.